# Powershell Script to pull all AD users and last time password was changed and date of change

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to create a script to extract all AD users from 3 different domains with their last logon date as well as the last time they changed their password and extract it to a CSV. I have the following code:

```
$data = @()
$domains = "example.exa.com "," example.com",” ex.example.com”
foreach($domain in $domains)
{
    $data | Foreach-Object –Process { get-aduser -filter * -server $domains -properties passwordlastset,lastlogondate | select name, passwordlastset,lastlogondate }
$data | Export-csv –Path C:\passwords.csv -notypeinformation
```

The following code does not produce any errors, but it runs infinitely with no results. Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it runs at all? At least one `}` is missing.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code:

- You define the three domains with leading or trailing spaces
- You loop through the $domains using iterating variable `$domain`, but in the loop you are using the complete array `$domains`
- $data is defined as (empty) array on top, but still you use it to loop through its elements (which aren't there) by piping to `Foreach-Object`
- Try to avoid adding items to an array with `+=` as it needs to reconstruct the **entire** array in memory on every addition

Try:

```
$domains = 'example.exa.com','example.com','ex.example.com'
$data = foreach($domain in $domains) {
    # just output the objects here, so they will be collected for you in variable $data
    Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server $domain -Properties PasswordLastSet, LastLogonDate | Select-Object Name, PasswordLastSet, LastLogonDate
}
$data | Export-csv –Path 'C:\passwords.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```